# Firebase Realtime Database not showing

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have integrated Firebase Realtime database with my android application. The data is getting printed on the console. When I run the application in emulator, the data is getting reflected in the emulator and it gets loaded.
But when I run the same application in my pysical android device I am not able to see the data from firebase and the page is blank, though the data is getting printed on the console here as well.

I am guessing there is some permission related tag that I am missing in Android Manifest. [image]

My Android Manifest.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.studydatascience">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StudyDataScience">
        <activity
            android:name=".newActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <..  some activities  ..>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-1234567891234567~0123456789" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StudyDataScience.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Build.gradle file

```
plugin {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rajendra.studydatascience"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 12
        versionName "2.8"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
}
```

This is the code to get the data from firebase

```
public void  fetch(String keyValue){
    Adapter adapter1 = new Adapter(newActivity.this,arrayList);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.view_recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    // Initialize Firebase
    DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions").child(keyValue);
    cartListRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        int questionCount = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
            String answer = dataSnapshot.child("answer").getValue(String.class);
            String question = dataSnapshot.child("question").getValue(String.class);
            answer = answer.replace("\\n", "\n").trim();
            arrayList.add(new QA(question,answer));
            Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: "+answer);
}
```

These are the rules of Firebase Realtime database

[image]

Sample Firebase database json file

```
{ 
"questions": {
"machine learning": [
  {
    "answer": "Tensor has three indices where the first points to the row, the second to the column and the third one to the axis",
    "question": "What is a Tensor?"
  }
],
"python": [
  {
    "answer": "Different data structures in Python include \n Builtin Data Structures:\n List, Dictionary, Tuple, Set \n UserDefined Data Structure:\n Stack, Queue, Tree, Linked List, Graph, HashMap",
    "question": "What are the different data structures in Python?"
  }
],
"deep learning": [
  {
    "answer": "perceptron is a singlelayer neural network. It consists of input value, weight and bias, activation function. Input value is multiplies with weight and added to bias, then activation function is applied to it.",
    "question": "What is a perceptron?"
  }
]}}
```

Comment: Can you share your android manifest and build.gradle files?

Comment: Check your RTDB rules.

Comment: What is the exact line of code that produces that error? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: @jbmcle I have checked my RTDB rules. This is true for read and write.

Comment: @AlexMamo The data gets printed on the console as shared in the image and then I get permission error after that.

Comment: @tomerpacific I have added the relevant files.

Comment: Please show us the rules and the code that interacts with Firebase.

Comment: @AlexMamo added the code

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added sample json file from database.